# SQL Server 2005 how to use union syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query

```
select c.RequestedByEmployeeID 
from Company c with (NOLOCK)
```

which works, but when I try this, it fails

```
select 
    c.RequestedByEmployeeID as ResponsibleLawyerID

union

select 
    c.RequestedByEmployeeID as ResponsibleLawyerID
from
    Company c with (NOLOCK)
order by
    c.CompanyID
```

with this error:

> Msg 107, Level 16, State 2, Line 44
>   The column prefix 'c' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
>
> Msg 107, Level 16, State 2, Line 44
>   The column prefix 'c' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a valid sql query `select 
    c.RequestedByEmployeeID as ResponsibleLawyerID`

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the alias and repeat the `FROM` clause:

```
select c.CompanyId, c.RequestedByEmployeeID as ResponsibleLawyerID
from Company c
union
select c.CompanyId, c.RequestedByEmployeeID as ResponsibleLawyerID
from Company c
order by CompanyID;
```

Note that you need to select the column.  If you don't want to select the column but you want to order by it, then one solution is a subquery.  Your query is basically non-sensical (selecting the same column), so adding the company seems reasonable.

The `order by` refers to the result of the `union`, not to a particular subquery.  So, an alias is not appropriate.

The use of `union` means that you don't want duplicates, so the database incurs a performance penalty for removing them.  If you don't care, then use `union all`.